# Laravel commands giving me errors, parse error, expecting `'&'' or `"variable

Tags: php, macos, laravel, xampp

I am using osx, and have composer and  Laravel both installed. I downloaded laravel fine, and chmodded the storage folder. Now if I run any command make: I am getti getting the following error:

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `'&'' or`"variable (T_VARIABLE)"'
>   in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/eco/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
>   on line 484

I have run `php -v` in my terminal which returns:

```
PHP 7.1.4 (cli) (built: May 10 2017 16:03:28) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

Inside my bash_profile I have the following:

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
export XAMPP_HOME=/Applications/XAMPP
export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin/php-7.1.4:${PATH}
export PATH
```

and when I echo my path I have:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php-7.1.4:/Users/user/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

I also ran 'which php' which returns:

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

Composer is installed and laravel is too:
[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this, or a way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this post can be useful, it is something with your php versions.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16674